# 14 years old cat refuses to eat after operation

Tags: cats, health, stress

As mentioned in the title.  
Seven days ago our **14 y.o. cat had an operation** because he had developed a stone in his bladder. The operation went well and the doctor says that he is really well (x-rays, blood, urine tests, etc. are all as expected). While at the vet's -for five days- he was tube-fed for his inner wounds to heal.  
Two days ago he came back home. Ever since, **he refuses to eat anything**. We already tried his favorite cans, treats. He will not eat. He just **drinks water**.

Does anyone have any **idea or "tricks" on how to persuade him to eat**?

Comment: Try to mix some of the jelly of the wet food into the water. So you can find out if it is the taste or the non-fluidity of the food which stops the cat from eating.

Comment: And welcome to pets.SE :) I am sure here is some experienced cat person to give you a real answer :)

Comment: *"Try to mix some of the jelly of the wet food into the water"* Thank you @Allerleirauh . His favourite jello was a chicken one. Tried it. Got a sniff and turned the other way :(

Comment: If a cat hasn't eaten anything at all for 24 hours you should trat it as a medical emergency and immediately call your vet. Cats are very prone to develop a fatty liver if they don't eat.

Comment: Thank you @Elmy We already called him and he gave it another day. He said that the stress he would go through if forced fed by strangers (his staff) would cause him more harm since he has such a skittish personality and finds very difficult acclimating in new environments and strangers.

Comment: If a human was tube-fed I am sure there would be some diet plan to help this person comp with normal food again... Did you get some recommendations from your vet?

Comment: Not at all @Allerleirauh .His only concern is for the cat to start eating again whatever the food may be. And we have only a few hours left. I don't know :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My quick fix is this: Take a can of his favorite wet food. Put about a quarter of his usual daily portion into a food blender and add enouch water to make a very liquid, easy to drink shake. The shake should be at room temperature or slightly above to develop the aroma of the food.

This should get at least some calories into him and get in on his way to improvement.

If you don't havbe a food blender, mash the food with a fork very fine. But in my experience you cannot get a smooth, even texture with a fork.